# Chart.js loading slow in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, chart.js

I'm using Chart.js and i have problem with loading.
I'm using Google Chrome and when i try to load the page with charts it takes about 1 min to load the charts and when i try to load it from Firefox it loads immediately without any delay.
I tried on another PC and it works without delay but only on my PC is slow.
Tried to reinstall the browser and again with delay.
Don't know what more to say.

Comment: without any kinda code we can just guess... could be cache e.g. ff has cached an e.g. 20Mb data file and in chrome its not... or if you're getting data via Ajax and the backend is bitchy to request's from chrome or, or, or ;)  did you tried safari or IE?

Comment: Yes i tried them a minute ago and it works wihout delay.

Comment: anything in the console? What does the network tab say?

Comment: Nothing in console, what do u mean with network tab(its in localhost)

Comment: My fault after loading the chart console says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 520 ()"

Comment: I had similar issues, but could solved it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49840992/chart-js-too-slow-rendering-vertical-stacked-bars-chart/49841137